# Optimizing packet validation based on unlikelihood of cheaters?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation, security

I'm working on a whiteboard app that uses canvas and everyone in the room can see and draw on the board. So basically when one person draws a packet is sent to the server and then broadcasted to everyone else in the room.

This works fine and all but I heard of the importance of validation checks of packets. For a brush update I might have to check something like this:

- Loop through each point in the points array to ensure they're valid points
- Is the color a valid hexidecimal value? (expensive RegEx test)
- Is the line width an int in the valid range?

And for what, exactly? I'm trying to think of the worst thing that can happen and I guess it'd be someone sending a string instead of a number and causing the javascript to get glitchy on the rest of the room's participants.

It just seems like so much server processing just for something that 99.99% of the time won't be doing anything because most people don't try to do packet injection. None of this data is stored on the server anyway so it's not like it puts the server in an invalid state either. Maybe it would be better to do validation on the client side instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly speculative, but I agree it seems unnecessary to carry out these checks on the server.

Ultimately the importance of data integrity / likely-hood of people trying to send false / invalid data is impossible for us (but not you) to know. If the outcome of the result is very important, and there is a high likely-hood of people trying to influence that result, then yes, you should probably be validating it.

If however you are simply trying to improve the integrity of your own data, then I agree that performing some simple checks on the client before sending the data is the way to go.